# Join latest value to table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`.

I am having a table called `companies` and a table `fundamentals`.

I would like to join the latest values of `fundamentals` to the `companies` table, whereas latest is the `created_at` in `fundamentals`.

Please find below my minimum example on db-fiddle:

[db-fiddle example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dCrJv5igaTyTuhJhN63fHx/0)

My current query looks like the following:

```
select
    *
from
    companies c
left outer join fundamentals f on
    f.companies_id = c.id
order by
    f.created_at DESC;
```

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look up which row to join on in a corelated sub-query.

```
select
  *
from
  companies c
left outer join
  fundamentals f
    on f.id = (
      SELECT id
        FROM fundamentals
       WHERE companies_id = c.id
    ORDER BY created_at DESC
       LIMIT 1
    )
ORDER BY
  c.name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function:

```
select *
from companies c left outer join
     (select f.*,
             row_number() over (partition by f.companies_id order by f.created_at desc) as seqnum
      from fundamentals f
     ) f
     on f.companies_id = c.id and f.seqnum = 1
order by f.created_at DESC;
```

Comment: OP's MySQL is 5.7